# Why is my UITableViewCell text overlapping the UITableView Cell Image?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView that has various cells that pulls in larger sized jpeg images. The issue at hand is that these images appear weird when someone clicks on the actual cell. For instance it appears as if the edge of the cell text over laps the image when clicked on. I also have some 40x40 PNGS on some other cells and they appear fine. I have attached 2 images that show the issue. The picture which is a JPG looks messed up. However the 40x40 PNG looks fine. How do I stream line this?

Normal:
[image]

Not Normal:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the code used to create the custom `UITabelViewCell`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhhh found the solution myself. I was getting the behavior due to incorrect remote image sizes.

The following piece of advice helped me.

http://iosdeveloperforums.com/f9/fixed-width-cell-images-afnetworking-96.html

Thanks everyone